# in shiny, how to plot from sliderinput that contains adding columns based on selectinputs

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to R and am trying to create Shiny app.
The app contains `sliderInput` to determine the investment amount.
The `selectInput` to determine vehicle type to invest in (`car` or `motorcycle`)
and another `selectInput` to pick the brand `name`.

My requests are:

1. After selecting the vehicle type (`car` or `motorcycle`), automatically select the rows that contain the selected vehicle type ( for example "cars")
2. After that, sum the values in `profit` column and divide each one by the total to calculate each brand name contribution in total profits.
3. Add new column that contains percentage of each brand `name`
4. Then add new column that contains multiplication of the `sliderInput` value to this percentage to calculate the expected profit if we invested the amount in `sliderInput`.
5. Then create bar plot for each brand `name` with their profits

   Here is the code  :

   ```
   library(shiny)
   library(dplyr)
   library(plotly)

   df1<-
   data.frame (
   Vehicle_type=c("CAR","CAR","CAR","MOTORCYCLE","MOTORCYCLE","MOTORCYCLE"),Brand_Name=c("ford","Honda","Audi","SYM","Honda","Harley"),revenues=(as.integer(c("526","552","445","222","223","300"))),cost=(as.integer(c("426","427","325","172","178","235"))),profit=(as.integer(c("100","125","120","50","45","65"))),branch1=(as.integer(c("10","15","12","6","5","5"))),branch2=(as.integer(c("3","4","7","6","4","9"))))
   shinyUI(fluidPage(titlePanel("Vehicles"),
   sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(sliderInput("bins", "investment:", min = 1000,max = 10000,value = 5000),
   selectInput("ProductId","Vehicle type:",choices=unique(df1$Vehicle_type)),
   selectInput("nameId","Vehicle Brand Name:",choices=NULL),
   selectInput("IndicatorId","Select Indicator:",choices=c("profit","cost","revenues",selected="revenues"))),
   mainPanel(plotlyOutput("Test2", height = "250px")))))
   ```

server

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

shinyServer(function(session,input, output) {

observe({
print(input$ProductId)
df2<-df1%>%filter(Vehicle_type==input$ProductId) %>% select(Brand_Name)
updateSelectInput(session,"nameId","Vehicle Brand Name:",choices=unique(df2))
IndicatorSum<- reactive({df2 %>% pull(input$IndicatorId) %>% sum()})
df3<-mutate(df2,perctcontcl=input$IndicatorId/IndicatorSum)
df4<-mutate(df3,perctcontout=perctcontcl*input$bins)
output$Test2 <- renderPlotly({
  Test2 <- plot_ly(
  df4, x = ~Brand_Name, y = ~get(input$IndicatorId), type = "bar",color=~Brand_Name)})
  })
 })

    shinyServer(function(input, output) {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a working example based on your idea with a few fixes and a little help from [dplyr NSE](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

```
#Add stringsAsFactors = FALSE to data.frame to solve ghost factor issue downstream in plotly
df1<-
  data.frame (
    Vehicle_type=c("CAR","CAR","CAR","MOTORCYCLE","MOTORCYCLE","MOTORCYCLE"),Brand_Name=c("ford","Honda","Audi","SYM","Honda","Harley"),revenues=(as.integer(c("526","552","445","222","223","300"))),cost=(as.integer(c("426","427","325","172","178","235"))),profit=(as.integer(c("100","125","120","50","45","65"))),branch1=(as.integer(c("10","15","12","6","5","5"))),branch2=(as.integer(c("3","4","7","6","4","9"))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


shinyServer(function(session,input, output) {
  observe({
    print(input$ProductId)
   #df2<-df1%>%filter(Vehicle_type==input$ProductId) %>% select(Brand_Name)
    df2<-df1%>%filter(Vehicle_type==input$ProductId)
   #updateSelectInput(session,"nameId","Vehicle Brand Name:",choices=unique(df2))
    updateSelectInput(session,"nameId","Vehicle Brand Name:",choices=unique(df2$Brand_Name))
    print(input$IndicatorId)
    print(df2)
   #IndicatorSum<- reactive({df2 %>% pull(input$IndicatorId) %>% sum()})
    IndicatorSum<- df2 %>% pull(input$IndicatorId) %>% sum()
    print(IndicatorSum)
    #browser()
    df3<-mutate(df2,!!quo_name(paste0(input$IndicatorId,'_perctcontcl')):=(!!sym(input$IndicatorId)/IndicatorSum)*input$bins)
    print(df3)
    #To check why we get ghost factor in plotly, we add stringsAsFactors = FALSE to data.frame to solve this issue
    print(str(df3))

    output$Test2 <- renderPlotly({
      Test2 <- plot_ly(
        df3, x = ~Brand_Name, 
        y = ~get(paste0(input$IndicatorId,'_perctcontcl')),
        #Here I think you need the updated Indicator after we multiply by input$bin  
        #y = ~get(input$IndicatorId), 
        type = "bar",color=~Brand_Name)})
  })
```